# How to extend WhitespaceTokenizer?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize

I need to use a tokenizer that splits words on whitespace but that doesn't split if the whitespace is whithin double parenthesis. Here an example:

```
My input-> term1 term2 term3 ((term4 term5)) term6
```

should produce this list of tokens:

```
term1, term2, term3, ((term4 term5)), term6.
```

I think that I can obtain this behaviour by extending Lucene [WhiteSpaceTokenizer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/WhitespaceTokenizer.html). How can I perform this extension?
Is there some other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to extend the Tokenizer, but i have here a nice (i think) solution with a regular expression:

```
\w+|\(\([\w\s]*\)\)
```

And a method that split a string by matched groups from the reg ex returning an array. Code example:

```
class Regex_ComandLine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "term1 term2 term3 ((term4 term5)) term6";    //your input
    String[] parsedInput = splitByMatchedGroups(input, "\\w+|\\(\\([\\w\\s]*\\)\\)");

    for (String arg : parsedInput) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}

static String[] splitByMatchedGroups(String string,
                                            String patternString) {
    List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher regexMatcher = Pattern.compile(patternString).matcher(string);

    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
    }

    return matchList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

}

The output:

```
term1
term2
term3
((term4 term5))
term6
```

Hope this help you.

Please note that the following code with the usual `split()`:

```
String[] parsedInput = input.split("\\w+|\\(\\([\\w\\s]*\\)\\)");
```

will return you nothing or not what you want beacuse it only check delimiters.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll use this way is simplest and I can obtain the same results than by extending WhitespaceTokenizer. Thank u again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by extending `WhitespaceTokenizer`, but I expect it will be easier if you write a [`TokenFilter`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenFilter.html) that reads from a `WhitespaceTokenizer` and pastes together consecutive tokens based on the number of parentheses.

Overriding [`incrementToken`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_3_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream.html#incrementToken%28%29) is the main task when writing a `Tokenizer`-like class. I once did this myself; [the result](https://github.com/larsmans/lucene-stanford-lemmatizer/blob/master/src/nl/rug/eco/lucene/EnglishLemmaTokenizer.java) might serve as an example (though for technical reasons, I couldn't make my class a `TokenFilter`).